# Getting content of partial html in DomDocument

Tags: php, dom

I have a string:

```
 $string = 'some text <img src="www">';
```

I want to get the image source and the text.
Here is what I have:

```
  $doc= new DOMDocument();  
  $doc->loadHTML($string);  
  $nodes=$doc->getElementsByTagName ('img');
```

From $nodes->item(0) I get the image source.
How can I get the the "some text"?

Comment: Basics first: the "some text" is not part of the image tag, sol selecting by 'img' tag seems a bit odd

Comment: It was my first task to get the img src

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For simple cases like this, try:

```
$doc->documentElement->textContent
```

Answer (score 2):

`textContent`, or with `DOMXPath`s `$xpath->query('//text()')`

Answer (score 0):

You could make it like jQuery in javascript. Wrap the whole string with anything, and get this. Then you can get the TextNode, which contains this text.

```
$string = 'some text <img src="www">';  
$string = '<div id="wrapper">' . $string . '</div>';

$nodes = $doc->getElementById('wrapper');
```